# does finite dimensional representations of bialgebras separate elements?

Tags: hopf-algebras, bialgebras

let $B$ be a bialgebra over a field (i.e. associative, coassociative, unitary and counitary, maybe it  has an antipode or maybe not). If $b\in B$ acts by zero on every finite dimensional representation of $B$, then necesarily $b=0$?

Answer (score 2):

No, it may not even have any non-trivial finite dimensional representations. For example, take the group algebra $kG$, where $G$ is a simple group with cardinality greater than that of the infinite field $k$.

Comment: but assuming something in the bialgebra? for instance if the bialgebra is finitely generated as algebra?

Comment: Since finitely generated linear groups are residually finite by a theorem of Malcev, if you take an infinite finitely generated simple group (like Thompson's group V), then all its finite dimensional representations collapse the group.

Comment: For a finitely generated group or monoid, the finite dimensional representations separate points of the monoid algebra iff the monoid is residually finite.

Comment: thanks for this answer, now I have a better view. Also Peter Schauenburg pointed out to me that the relation $ab\sim 1$ (in the free algebra generated by a and b)  do not imply $ba\sim 1$, so the element ba-1 is not zero in $k\{a,b\}/(ba\sim 1)$, but maps as zero to every f.d. representation.